# Failing to push to heroku master with npm script "postinstall"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack, gulp

I have the `postinstall` script that I assume gets called whenever you do `git push heroku master`. But for some reason the push is failing. I am on windows and had to use the `cross-env` package for some of the scripts. I think this may be causing it to fail, but I am not sure.

Here is an image of the terminal output:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRSUC.png)

**Heroku logs at the bottom**

Here are the scripts:

```
"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack && gulp",
"postinstall": "npm run build"
```

Here are the webpack and gulp files:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'public/build/bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'public/build/bundle.map',
  },
  devtool: '#source-map',
  plugins:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? [
          new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
              NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
            },
          }),
          new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            compress: {
              warnings: true,
            },
          }),
        ]
      : [],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

---

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var gp_concat = require('gulp-concat');
var gp_rename = require('gulp-rename');
var gp_uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('css', () => {
  return gulp
    .src([
      './public/assets/css/font-awesome.main.css',
      './public/assets/css/ie8.css',
      './public/assets/css/main.css'
    ])
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9'))
    .pipe(gp_concat('style.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/build/css'));
});

gulp.task('build', () => {
  return gulp
    .src([
      './public/assets/js/jquery.min.js',
      './public/assets/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js',
      './public/assets/js/skel.min.js',
      './public/assets/js/util.js',
      './public/assets/js/ie/respond.min.js',
      './public/assets/js/main.js'
    ])
    .pipe(gp_concat('gulp-concat.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/min'))
    .pipe(gp_rename('vendor.min.js'))
    .pipe(gp_uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/build/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['css', 'build'], () => {});
```

---

```
2017-09-18T13:55:31.499365+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2017-09-18T13:55:31.499511+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-09-18T13_55_31_493Z-debug.log
2017-09-18T13:55:31.615780+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-09-18T13:55:33.147165+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-09-18T13:55:33.147188+00:00 app[web.1]: > snapshot@0.0.0 start /app
2017-09-18T13:55:33.147189+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2017-09-18T13:55:33.147190+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760733+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/client-sessions/lib/client-sessions.js:548
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760762+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw new Error("cannot set up sessions without a secret "+
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760764+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760765+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760770+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: cannot set up sessions without a secret or encryptionKey/signatureKe
y pair
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760770+00:00 app[web.1]:     at clientSessionFactory (/app/node_modules/client-sessions/lib/client-s
essions.js:548:11)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760771+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:35:3)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760771+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760772+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760772+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760773+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760773+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760774+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760773+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760774+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bin/www:7:11)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760775+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760775+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760775+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760776+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760776+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760776+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760777+00:00 app[web.1]:     at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760777+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
2017-09-18T13:55:33.760778+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrap_node.js:502:3
2017-09-18T13:55:33.774695+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-09-18T13:55:33.775459+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2017-09-18T13:55:33.776542+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! snapshot@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
2017-09-18T13:55:33.776626+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-09-18T13:55:33.776766+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2017-09-18T13:55:33.776875+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the snapshot@0.0.0 start script.
2017-09-18T13:55:33.776951+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additiona
l logging output above.
2017-09-18T13:55:33.783741+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-09-18T13:55:33.783984+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2017-09-18T13:55:33.784118+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-09-18T13_55_33_780Z-debug.log
2017-09-18T13:55:33.871079+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-09-18T13:55:33.883665+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-09-18T13:55:52.250660+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-09-18T13:55:52.048172+00:00 app[api]: Set SESSION_SECRET config vars by user tbaustin1992@gmail.com
2017-09-18T13:55:52.048172+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user tbaustin1992@gmail.com
2017-09-18T13:55:55.840695+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-09-18T13:55:58.323084+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-09-18T13:55:58.323119+00:00 app[web.1]: > snapshot@0.0.0 start /app
2017-09-18T13:55:58.323120+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2017-09-18T13:55:58.323121+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-09-18T13:55:58.990350+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:18) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0,
 use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mo
ngoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
2017-09-18T13:55:59.019980+00:00 app[web.1]: Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next ma
jor release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple cred
entials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.
2017-09-18T13:55:59.068033+00:00 app[web.1]: DB CONNECT SUCCESS
2017-09-18T13:55:59.698175+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-09-18T13:56:08.437795+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/js/main.js" host=ta-snapshot.herokuapp
.com request_id=a6710e07-a8f0-4745-9e1c-a235cb2a0252 fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 b
ytes=3324 protocol=https
2017-09-18T13:56:08.297473+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=ta-snapshot.herokuapp.com request_id=b
947354f-896e-464c-aadc-fc02cfc839e1 fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=39ms status=200 bytes=1680 protoc
ol=https
2017-09-18T13:56:08.438162+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/js/util.js" host=ta-snapshot.herokuapp
.com request_id=bf8023a7-3cb1-4747-bd3c-a1ffaf1b723c fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 b
ytes=12722 protocol=https
2017-09-18T13:56:08.437227+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/js/skel.min.js" host=ta-snapshot.herok
uapp.com request_id=71672b98-4aa0-4afd-81ea-6fb051a8c62f fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=2
00 bytes=9373 protocol=https
2017-09-18T13:56:08.366497+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/js/jquery.min.js" host=ta-snapshot.her
okuapp.com request_id=1a37732e-e61e-49ac-b987-51eb0ea99e9e fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=22ms statu
s=200 bytes=96247 protocol=https
2017-09-18T13:56:08.298920+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 200 26.782 ms - 1477
2017-09-18T13:56:08.361855+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /assets/css/main.css 200 12.223 ms - 50410
2017-09-18T13:56:08.366349+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /assets/js/jquery.min.js 200 1.785 ms - 95957
2017-09-18T13:56:08.432865+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /assets/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js 200 1.283 ms - 12113
2017-09-18T13:56:08.435508+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /assets/js/skel.min.js 200 3.256 ms - 9085
2017-09-18T13:56:08.437044+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /assets/js/util.js 200 2.149 ms - 12433
2017-09-18T13:56:08.494412+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /build/bundle.js 200 1.214 ms - 1577443
2017-09-18T13:56:08.437610+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /assets/js/main.js 200 2.387 ms - 3037
2017-09-18T13:56:08.364794+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/css/main.css" host=ta-snapshot.herokua
pp.com request_id=ff43a00a-5fcf-4a41-b0f3-a971d06bac90 fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=20ms status=20
0 bytes=50700 protocol=https
2017-09-18T13:56:08.434158+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/js/jquery.poptrox.min.js" host=ta-snap
shot.herokuapp.com request_id=83fd62f8-f6cc-486b-bf4b-4041a275a249 fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3m
s status=200 bytes=12402 protocol=https
2017-09-18T13:56:08.518895+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/build/bundle.js" host=ta-snapshot.herokuapp.c
om request_id=2dd801e9-e899-4d4a-8a52-dc1fc67b613c fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=44ms status=200 by
tes=1577736 protocol=https
2017-09-18T13:56:09.148354+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /assets/css/font-awesome.min.css 200 4.151 ms - 29063
2017-09-18T13:56:09.146219+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" host=ta-snap
shot.herokuapp.com request_id=39dfd327-c09a-45e4-855a-ebffaa27257c fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8m
s status=200 bytes=29353 protocol=https
2017-09-18T13:56:09.517771+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /account/currentuser 200 3.193 ms - 38
2017-09-18T13:56:09.548178+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /api/post?lat=40.7504753&lng=-73.9932668 200 26.721 ms - 39
2017-09-18T13:56:09.513895+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/account/currentuser" host=ta-snapshot.herokua
pp.com request_id=65c8a776-9d5a-47fd-b477-db435f78b797 fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200
 bytes=245 protocol=https
2017-09-18T13:56:09.549304+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/post?lat=40.7504753&lng=-73.9932668" host
=ta-snapshot.herokuapp.com request_id=16272576-6b17-4106-8836-afe0ce8bb34e fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms se
rvice=33ms status=200 bytes=246 protocol=https
2017-09-18T13:56:10.263855+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ta-snapshot.herokuapp.com r
equest_id=2a88ed05-0fad-4990-b29a-30ab227c02fc fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15ms status=404 bytes=
248 protocol=https
2017-09-18T13:56:10.259213+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /favicon.ico 404 9.124 ms - 41
2017-09-18T13:56:28.009172+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/account/register" host=ta-snapshot.herokuapp
.com request_id=cf25e1dc-d704-4ea4-a4c0-f0688fdf8f83 fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=241ms status=200
 bytes=569 protocol=https
2017-09-18T13:56:28.001827+00:00 app[web.1]: { __v: 0,
2017-09-18T13:56:28.001851+00:00 app[web.1]:   _id: 59bfd08b43dd250012c92e1e,
2017-09-18T13:56:28.001852+00:00 app[web.1]:   timestamp: 2017-09-18T13:56:27.968Z,
2017-09-18T13:56:28.001853+00:00 app[web.1]:   password: '$2a$10$70PiciKOFgd04G090zECtOGH2ufENQk7/3vDFkc3x0QgTdNEc8k72',
2017-09-18T13:56:28.001854+00:00 app[web.1]:   username: 'tbaustin' }
2017-09-18T13:56:28.008043+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /account/register 200 238.870 ms - 128
2017-09-18T13:56:44.301208+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /api/post?lat=40.75076789772389&lng=-73.99052021796876 200 13.201 ms -
39
2017-09-18T13:56:44.302363+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/post?lat=40.75076789772389&lng=-73.990520
21796876" host=ta-snapshot.herokuapp.com request_id=6b8e57d1-543d-4b0d-9447-28a7861c365a fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1
connect=1ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=246 protocol=https
2017-09-18T13:56:45.284274+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/post?lat=40.75219835694907&lng=-73.993953
44550783" host=ta-snapshot.herokuapp.com request_id=9472bd9e-c88b-4ca0-888f-ba65dbc3cf83 fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1
connect=1ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=246 protocol=https
2017-09-18T13:56:45.284477+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /api/post?lat=40.75219835694907&lng=-73.99395344550783 200 10.603 ms -
39
2017-09-18T13:56:47.609169+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/post?lat=40.75920391164151&lng=-73.990541
67564088" host=ta-snapshot.herokuapp.com request_id=2ba05865-34bf-433a-a6ba-388fcddfa95a fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1
connect=1ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=246 protocol=https
2017-09-18T13:56:47.607576+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /api/post?lat=40.75920391164151&lng=-73.99054167564088 200 4.460 ms - 3
9
2017-09-18T13:57:12.601209+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /api/post 200 31.164 ms - 341
2017-09-18T13:57:12.604731+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/post" host=ta-snapshot.herokuapp.com req
uest_id=cb2ae99f-745c-460b-ac31-8c12fe476a40 fwd="24.192.32.162" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=37ms status=200 bytes=55
0 protocol=https
2017-09-18T14:33:24.565734+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-09-18T14:33:24.567184+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-09-18T14:33:25.533659+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2017-09-18T14:33:25.472561+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-09-18T14:33:25.653495+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2017-09-20T15:41:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user tbaustin1992@gmail.com
2017-09-20T15:41:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
```

Comment: What is the Heroku error?

Comment: Added heroku logs at the bottom

Comment: Well, looks to be an error related to a node module - `/app/node_modules/client-sessions/lib/client-sessions.js:548` - any guidance in that module's README about setting a `secret or encryptionKey/signatureKey`?

Comment: See the 'Cryptography' section - https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-sessions

Comment: My guess is that this value needs to be set up as some sort of environment variable, probably in part of your Webpack build process. Have you done anything to set those values when running your app locally?

Comment: I store the `SESSION_SECRET` in the .env file but in heroku I set the variable as well in the config variables.

Comment: Just throwing this out there - in your Webpack config, under the DefinePlugin, add `"SESSION_SECRET": JSON.stringify(process.env.SESSION_SECRET)` - I'm not a Webpack expert by any stretch of the imagination, but this helped me through a similar problem... put it next to `process.env`, not as an attribute of `process.env`...

Comment: That worked lol, how did you know to do that ? If you dont mind me asking

Comment: In an app that I was working on, there were a few environment variables that needed to be included in the build process. I wasn't using an .env file in my config. I just included the environment variables like this in my Webpack config, and they were included in the postinstall build. I actually haven't used a .env file in any of my Webpack projects, though I know it's a thing... so I can't really say what the problem you were facing was.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154942/discussion-between-taylor-austin-and-skwidbreth).

Answer (score 1):

As provided by **@skwidbreth** I was getting a session_secret error in the heroku logs. I guess it was not being provided or defined somehow. I have it defined in the .env file and in the config vars in heroku, but it still didn't work.

What made this work is by changing the `webpack` file to include the `SESSION_SECRET`. I will post the new `webpack.config.js`

You can see under next to `process.env` is where I put it as recommended.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'public/build/bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'public/build/bundle.map',
  },
  devtool: '#source-map',
  plugins:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? [
          new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
              NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
            },
            SESSION_SECRET: JSON.stringify(process.env.SESSION_SECRET),
          }),
          new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            compress: {
              warnings: true,
            },
          }),
        ]
      : [],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```